I am trying to create a flow that sends a reminder email if there has been no email activity in the account for the past 7 days
How to fetch data/records from account where activity type is email in flow?
I am trying to create a flow that sends a reminder email if there has been no email activity in the account for the past 7 days.
I have tried to find ActivityHistory object in flow
